# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attr

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

---

Hi Experts,
I have this controller code which is throwing the above mentioned error. It was working fine till yesterday, I have no clue what colleague did to this code and today I am seeing the error:

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'sideForm' available as request attribute

Can you please suggest me where to look for this kind of error. Am I making any mistake in POST or GET method declaration or returning something wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

```
package com.att.analytics.ui;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.si.myworld.business.AdminChart;
import com.si.myworld.business.Chart;
import com.si.myworld.dao.AdminChartSummaryData;
import com.si.myworld.dao.BulletinData;
import com.si.myworld.dao.ChartData;

@RequestMapping("/index.html")
@Controller
public class IndexController {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class);

/**
 * Called to load the page initially (GET request)
 * 
 * @param model
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCharts(ModelMap model) {

    Chart chart = new Chart();
    chart.setTimeline("Monthly");
    chart.setStartDt("mm/dd/yyyy");
    chart.setEndDt("mm/dd/yyyy");

    AdminChartSummaryData acsd = new AdminChartSummaryData();
    List<AdminChart> list = acsd.getLandingChartDataList();

    if (list.size() == 4) {
        Chart chart1 = new Chart(list.get(0));
        Chart chart2 = new Chart(list.get(1));
        Chart chart3 = new Chart(list.get(2));
        Chart chart4 = new Chart(list.get(3));
        model.put("chart1", chart1);
        model.put("chart2", chart2);
        model.put("chart3", chart3);
        model.put("chart4", chart4);

        log.info("chart 1>>>>" + chart1);


        ChartData cd = new ChartData();

        String chartOneDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart1
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartTwoDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart2
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartThreeDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart3
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartFourDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart4
                .getChartSubgroup());

        String breadcrumbOne = chart1.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart1.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbTwo = chart2.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart2.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbThree = chart3.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart3.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbFour = chart4.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart4.getChartSubgroup();


        BulletinData bd = new BulletinData();
        String bulletin = bd.getBulletinData();

        model.put("sideForm", chart);



        model.put("chartOneDatasource", chartOneDatasource);
        model.put("chartTwoDatasource", chartTwoDatasource);
        model.put("chartThreeDatasource", chartThreeDatasource);
        model.put("chartFourDatasource", chartFourDatasource);

        model.put("breadcrumbOne", breadcrumbOne);
        model.put("breadcrumbTwo", breadcrumbTwo);
        model.put("breadcrumbThree", breadcrumbThree);
        model.put("breadcrumbFour", breadcrumbFour);

        model.put("bulletin", bulletin);
    }

    return "land";
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loadCharts(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("sideForm") Chart chart) {

    String from_date = request.getParameter("startDt");
    String to_date = request.getParameter("endDt");

    chart.setStartDt(from_date);
    chart.setEndDt(to_date);

    ChartData cd = new ChartData();

    BulletinData bd = new BulletinData();
    String bulletin = bd.getBulletinData();



    AdminChartSummaryData acsd = new AdminChartSummaryData();
    List<AdminChart> list = acsd.getLandingChartDataList();
    if (list.size() == 4) {
        Chart chart1 = new Chart(list.get(0));
        Chart chart2 = new Chart(list.get(1));
        Chart chart3 = new Chart(list.get(2));
        Chart chart4 = new Chart(list.get(3));
        model.put("chart1", chart1);
        model.put("chart2", chart2);
        model.put("chart3", chart3);
        model.put("chart4", chart4);


        String chartOneDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart1
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartTwoDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart2
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartThreeDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart3
                .getChartSubgroup());
        String chartFourDatasource = cd.fetchChartDatasourceName(chart4
                .getChartSubgroup());

        model.put("chartOneDatasource", chartOneDatasource);
        model.put("chartTwoDatasource", chartTwoDatasource);
        model.put("chartThreeDatasource", chartThreeDatasource);
        model.put("chartFourDatasource", chartFourDatasource);

        String breadcrumbOne = chart1.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart1.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbTwo = chart2.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart2.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbThree = chart3.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart3.getChartSubgroup();
        String breadcrumbFour = chart4.getChartGroup() + ">>"
                + chart4.getChartSubgroup();


        model.put("breadcrumbOne", breadcrumbOne);
        model.put("breadcrumbTwo", breadcrumbTwo);
        model.put("breadcrumbThree", breadcrumbThree);
        model.put("breadcrumbFour", breadcrumbFour);
    }
    return "land";
}


@ModelAttribute("timeline")
public Collection<String> populateTimeline() {
    return Arrays.asList("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly",
            "Annually", "12_Month_Rolling");
}
}
```

This page gets values from a form shown below:

```
<form:form commandName="sideForm">
<div style="font-weight:bold; color:#000">Timeline</div>


<div style="margin:0 0 5px 0;"><form:select path="timeline" items="${timeline}" id="tm"/></div>

<div class="tofrom">From:</div>

<form:input path="startDt" id="from_date" size="7" maxlength="10" />

<div class="tofrom">To:</div>

<form:input path="endDt" id="to_date" size="7" maxlength="12" />

<input type="submit" value="Update Chart" />

</form:form>
```

Answer (score 37):

Make sure that your Spring form mentions the `modelAttribute="<Model Name"`.

**Example:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/greeting.html")
public class GreetingController {

 @ModelAttribute("greeting")
 public Greeting getGreetingObject() {
  return new Greeting();
 }

 /**
  * GET
  * 
  * 
  */
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String handleRequest() {
  return "greeting";
 }

 /**
  * POST
  * 
  * 
  */
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("greeting") Greeting greeting, BindingResult result){
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
  mv.addObject("greeting", greeting);  
  return mv;
 }
}
```

In your JSP :

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="greeting" method="POST" action="greeting.html">
```

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you declare the bean associated with the form in GET method of the associated controller and also add it in the model `model.addAttribute("uploadItem", uploadItem);` which contains `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` annotation.

For example UploadItem.java is associated with myform.jsp and controller is SecureAreaController.java

myform.jsp contains

```
<form:form action="/securedArea" commandName="uploadItem" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form:form>
```

### MyFormController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/securedArea")
@Controller
public class SecureAreaController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
            UploadItem uploadItem = new UploadItem(); // declareing

            model.addAttribute("uploadItem", uploadItem); // adding in model
    return "securedArea/upload";
}

}
```

As you can see I am declaring UploadItem.java in controller GET method.

Comment: Thanks @user473445. Adding the associated bean in GET method solved the problem for me.

Comment: good explanation.thanku somuch

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a BindingResult parameter to methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` which have a `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameters. After each `@ModelAttribute` parameter, Spring looks for a BindingResult in the next parameter position (order is important).

So try changing:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loadCharts(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("sideForm") Chart chart) 
...
```

To:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loadCharts(@ModelAttribute("sideForm") Chart chart, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
...
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I wonder why solution suggested by andronikus and user473445 did not worked ? Any way thanks to Rob Beardow

Answer (score 4):

I worked on this same issue and I am sure I have found out the exact reason for it.

**Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute**

If your successView property value (name of jsp page) is the same as your input page name, then second value of ModelAndView constructor must be match with the commandName of the input page.

E.g.

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td><a href="Login.html">Login</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>              
            <entry key="/Login.html">
                <ref bean="userController"/>
            </entry>
        </map>          
    </property>             
</bean>     
 <bean id="userController" class="controller.AddCountryFormController">     
       <property name="commandName"><value>country</value></property>
       <property name="commandClass"><value>controller.Country</value></property>        
       <property name="formView"><value>countryForm</value></property>
       <property name="successView"><value>countryForm</value></property>
   </bean>
```

**AddCountryFormController.java**

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;


public class AddCountryFormController extends SimpleFormController
{

    public AddCountryFormController(){
        setCommandName("Country.class");
    }

    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object command,BindException errors){

            Country country=(Country)command;

            System.out.println("calling onsubmit method !!!!!");

        return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(),"country",country);

    }

}
```

**Country.java**

```
package controller;

public class Country
{
    private String countryName;

    public void setCountryName(String value){
        countryName=value;
    }

    public String getCountryName(){
        return countryName;
    }

}
```

**countryForm.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form:form commandName="country" method="POST" >
            <table>
                    <tr><td><form:input path="countryName"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>
            </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
<html>
```

Input page `commandName="country"`
`ModelAndView Constructor as  return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(),"country",country);`
Means inputpage `commandName==ModeAndView(,"commandName",)`

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and changed `commandname=""` to `modelAttribute=""` in jsp page to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem as well. Here is my solution:

Below is the error while running a small Spring Application:-

```
*HTTP Status 500 - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/employe.jsp at line 12
9: <form:form method="POST" commandName="command"  action="/SpringWeb/addEmploye">
10:    <table>
11:     <tr>
12:         <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
13:         <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
14:     </tr>
15:     <tr>
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.employe_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(employe_jsp.java:185)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.employe_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(employe_jsp.java:120)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.employe_jsp._jspService(employe_jsp.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.*
```

In order to resolve this issue you need to do the following in the controller class:-

1. Change the import package from "`import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;`"
   to "`import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;`"...
2. Recompile and run the code... the problem should get resolved.

Comment: This is a different problem, it bears no relevance to the original question.