# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please help me. Im trying to use 2 Forms on 1 jsp. The first Form works just fine. When i try to submit the second form i get the IllegalStateException. I have already read a lot of things about this problem, but nothing could solve my current problem.

Form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<head>
    <%@ include file="../views/common/imports.jsp" %>
    <title>MARC</title>
</head>
<body onload="togglePieLines()">
    <%@ include file="../views/common/header.jsp"%>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="standard-form">
        <form:form commandName="unit" method="post" action="units" class="uk-form" id="unitForm">
            <!-- Allgemeine Informationen -->
            <table class="uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-text-small">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><spring:message code="units.generalInformation"/></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1 td-form-row"><spring:message code="units.id"/>&nbsp;*&nbsp;<form:errors path="unitId" class="uk-badge uk-badge-warning"/></td>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1"><form:input path="unitId" class="uk-form-width-medium" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.name"/>&nbsp;*&nbsp;<form:errors path="name" class="uk-badge uk-badge-warning"/></td>                   
                        <td>            
                            <form:input path="name" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.country"/>&nbsp;*&nbsp;<form:errors path="country" class="uk-badge uk-badge-warning"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                               <form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.bu"/></td>
                        <td><form:input path="bu" class="uk-form-width-medium" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.pie"/></td>
                        <td><form:checkbox id="pie" path="pie" onChange="togglePieLines()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="pieReason" style="display: none;">
                        <td><spring:message code="units.pieJustification"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                               <form:select path="pieReason" items="${pieReasonList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="pieSince" style="display: none;">
                        <td><spring:message code="units.pieSince"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="uk-form-icon">
                                   <i class="uk-icon-calendar"></i>
                                   <form:input path="pieSince" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                             </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Anwendungsparameter -->
            <table class="uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-text-small">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><spring:message code="units.applicationParameters"/></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1"><spring:message code="units.legalForm"/></td>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1">
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <form:select path="legalForm" items="${legalFormList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.group"/></td>
                        <td><form:checkbox path="consolidationType" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Verantwortlichkeiten -->
            <table class="uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-text-small">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><spring:message code="units.responsibilities"/></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1"><spring:message code="units.responsibleUnit"/></td>
                        <td class="uk-width-1-1">
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                               <form:select path="responsibleUnit" items="${userList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.responsibleRotation"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                               <form:select path="responsibleRotation" items="${userList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><spring:message code="units.responsibleNonAudit"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                               <form:select path="responsibleNonAudit" items="${userList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="input-center">
                <button class="uk-button" type="submit"><i class="uk-icon-save"></i>&nbsp;<spring:message code="button.save"/></button>
                <button class="uk-button" type="reset"><i class="uk-icon-undo"></i>&nbsp;<spring:message code="button.reset"/></button>
                <a class="uk-button" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/unitsOverview"><i class="uk-icon-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;<spring:message code="button.back"/></a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </form:form>
        <c:if test="${not empty showParentUnits}">
            <form:form commandName="parentUnit" method="post" action="parentUnits" class="uk-form">
                <!-- Zuordnung übergeordneter Einheiten -->
                <table class="uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-text-small">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6"><spring:message code="units.parentsAssignment"/></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uk-text-left">&nbsp;<spring:message code="units.parent"/></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><spring:message code="units.share"/></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><spring:message code="units.usb"/></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><spring:message code="units.fullLiability"/></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><spring:message code="units.consolidation"/></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"></td>
                        <tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="uk-form-row">
                                    <form:select path="parentUnitId" items="${unitList}" class="uk-form-width-medium" />
                               </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><input type="text" class="uk-form-width-mini"></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><input type="text" class="uk-form-width-mini"></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><button class="uk-button" type="submit"><i class="uk-icon-plus"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </c:if>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
function togglePieLines() {
    if ($('#pie').prop('checked')) {
         $('#pieReason').fadeIn(400);
         $('#pieSince').fadeIn(400);
    }
    else {
         $('#pieReason').fadeOut(400);
         $('#pieSince').fadeOut(400); 
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
package de.amana.marc;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import de.amana.marc.model.ParentUnit;
import de.amana.marc.model.Unit;
import de.amana.marc.service.ParentUnitService;
import de.amana.marc.service.UnitService;

@Controller
public class UnitsController
{

    private UnitService unitService;
    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="unitService")
    public void setUnitService(UnitService us){
        this.unitService = us;
    }

    private ParentUnitService parentUnitService;
    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="parentUnitService")
    public void setParentUnitService(ParentUnitService pus){
        this.parentUnitService = pus;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/units", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String unitForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 
        model = this.unitService.fillFormSelectBoxes(model);
        // Formobjekte
        model.addAttribute("unit", new Unit());
        model.addAttribute("parentUnit", new ParentUnit());

        return "units";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/units", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public String unitFormSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute Unit unit, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        model = this.unitService.fillFormSelectBoxes(model);
        //Validierung
        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            return "units";
        } 
        else {
            // Speichern in DB
            this.unitService.addUnit(unit);
            // Zuordnung übergeordneter Gesellschaften einblenden
            model.addAttribute("showParentUnits", true);
            // Form neu befüllen
            model.addAttribute("unit", unit);
            model.addAttribute("unitList", this.unitService.listUnits());
            ParentUnit newPu = new ParentUnit();
            newPu.setUnitId(unit.getUnitId());
            model.addAttribute("parentUnit", newPu);

            return "units";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/parentUnits", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public String parentUnitFormSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute ParentUnit parentUnit, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        // Formobjekt bearbeiten vor Speichern  
        ParentUnit newPu = new ParentUnit();        
        model = this.unitService.fillFormSelectBoxes(model);

        return "units";
    }
}
```

Full Stacktrace:
[image]

Sometimes the Stacktrace changes to:
[image]
This is kinda wierd, because i should be in submit and i have no clue why the first form has the problem

Comment: can you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: Just a second. I will upload the full stacktrace

Comment: Stacktrace is uploaded

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069958/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request)

Comment: have tried the solution there. i didnt work. So i guess no duplicate

Comment: Second stacktrace seems to indicate that it could not bind unit while rendering units.jsp. Is your get method working fine and you are running into issue only when trying to submit "/parentUnits" form? Can you post you ParentUnit and Unit class here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use attribute "modelAttribute" on your first form like this and use it in your controller Parameter like the same name:

```
<form:form commandName="unit" method="post" action="units" class="uk-form" id="unitForm" modelAttribute="unit">
```

and your second form also the same name in the Controller Parameter:

```
<form:form commandName="parentUnit" method="post" action="parentUnits" class="uk-form" modelAttribute="parentUnit">
```

Be sure to add the same name as added attribute in your model to access in your success .jsp