# JSP output plain text in Web Browser

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am using Eclipse, Spring MVC, Maven and Tomcat. This `index.jsp` displays exactly as show below in the web browser. It is not rendering properly.

Any idea what is wrong?

```
index.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
</body>
</html>

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Greeting");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("Index page");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's outputting `<%@page...` etc?

Comment: Yes, it's outputting <%@page

Comment: How did you create your JSP file? Where is it placed in your project? How are you accessing it (what URL you are using)?

Comment: I created it using Eclipse menu and it placed in WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/ I am accesing it with / as it runs

Comment: How are you accessing it?

Comment: Are you using an internal resource view resolver?

Comment: Yes, I am using InternalResourceViewResolver

Answer (score 0):

A controller has a GET and a POST RequestMethod.However at a quick glance you need to change @RequestMapping("/greeting") to @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting") just for starters. By default your jsp file should be in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views (Spring MVC Starter Project)

When you return a String - Spring MVC will look for a jsp with that .jsp. So in this example you just want to have greeting.jsp

```js
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

 /**
  * GET
  */

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest() {
// This will be used when you GET the URL
  return "greeting";
 }

 /**
  * POST
  */
 @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processSubmit(){

  // This will be used when you POST to the URL
  //TODO Do something here and it will put you right back in your page

  return "greeting";
 }
}
```

Go ahead and comment if you have any other questions. Also check my account for my other example [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069958/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request/1441829#1441829)

Hope this helps. Good Luck!

Just a note Spring has more RequestMethod's but GET and POST are the most used and easiest to understand.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/path") === @RequetMapping(value="/path")

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the only thing you're missing is to

Right click on the jsp page and click RUN AS, then RUN ON SERVER.