# how to get userid and password from database and pass to Method in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>User Login.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>User Login.</h4>
    <form:form method="post" name="loginForm" action="login-check">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" value="${form.name}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><form:input path="password" value="${form.password}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit"
                    value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="color: red">${error}</div>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/login-check")
    public ModelAndView  logincheck(@ModelAttribute Form person) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int value=service.checkLogin("name", "password");

        if(value>0)
        {

        return "loginsucess";

        }
        else
        {
            return "failure";
        }
    }
```

I have Form `Bean class`  in which we have `User Id` and `password` and Some more `field` are there with its `getter` and `setter` i want to take Input from `jsp` page and  i have to pass in `checkLogin method` here we define check Login

```
public int checkLogin(String userName, String userPassword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String SQL_QUERY = " from Form as o where o.userName=? and o.userPassword=?";

        int rowCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(SQL_QUERY);
        return rowCount;
    }
```

i am trying to get `jsp` Input Value but unable to get please suggest me how i ll get sot that  i can apply condition for this .

Comment: How you are loading your login page? Show us your controller for that.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/login-form")
 public String loginForm(Model model, Form field) {
  return "login";
 }  using this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a count query and set the parameter for the prepared statement:

```
 String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Form WHERE username = ? and o.userPassword=?";
int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, new Object[] { userName, userPassword});
```

Comment: OK but how i ll get value from Jsp page in contrller

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/Q2wxG8RNKrf2fMxqzKyhYN  this exception coming after call Login page

Comment: `service.checkLogin(person.getName(), person.getPassword());` should work

Comment: I did same but  when we  goIndex page to Login page then follwoing Exception showing which i sent u

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069958/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request

Comment: Greeting how i will define this class

Answer (score 0):

Do below changes in your code

```
@RequestMapping("/login-form")
public String loginForm(Model model, Form field) {
    model.addAttribute("person", new Form()); // added
    return "login";
}
```

Added `modelAttribute` in form. And do not specify **value** attribute in `form:input` only **path** attribute is required in your case.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person" name="loginForm" action="login-check">
    ...
    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    ...
```

Added **person** in `@ModelAttribute`.

```
@RequestMapping("/login-check")
    public ModelAndView  logincheck(@ModelAttribute("person") Form person) {
        ...
```

Now person object will get populated from jsp. Make sure you use valid database query.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/ZerDkkKUwnbcZBrL28XSC  This Exception come after click on Login Button

Comment: `SQLException: Table 'davdb.form' doesn't exist`